# How to implement change password in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using the security function (Bcrypt) of Spring. I want to implement a change password functionality in which first the old password is validated against an existing database password, then the user enters a new password and then confirms the password.

Comment: Please show us what you tried already.

Comment: can u please explain me basic flow coz till now i have just created jsp accepting 3 parameter oldPassword, newPassword, confirmNewPassword and then linked with controller.so how to get the oldPassword from db and then match to jsp field .as well as how to update newPassword . if u have some templates of this then post

Comment: Which encoding you are using to encrypt your password?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. We do need to see some prior research and effort here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when the user enters the field value for `oldPassword`, you have to take that value to `controller` and encrypt it using the `PasswordEncode`, assuming that you are using `BCryptPasswordEncoding`:

```
PasswordEncoder token = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
token.matches(oldPasswordFromScreen, oldPasswordFromDB);
```

Above code will match the password and return a `boolean` value. If the two passwords matches, you will take the new password and encrypt it using,

```
token.encode(newPassword);
```

Comment: This is for validation . i have already done that. i want to implement change password form. so how to get the old password from database n how to match.

Comment: If you have already done the above validation, then it means you can get oldPassword from DB right? Also, what do you think `token.matches(oldPasswordFromScreen, oldPasswordFromDB);` this code is doing?

Comment: You have said "I want to implement a change password functionality in which first the old password is validated against an existing database password", it doesn't mean you have implemented it already. We are here to help but be specific about your problem. Try to show your code which is not working.